# Collections of Traits with types generics in Scala 2.10

Tags: scala, generics, reflection, scala-2.10

I'm trying to build collections of objects, defined at run time and using type generics, by referring to their superclass (well, trait), but I'm having a tough time transforming them back into the child objects.  Some example code and results:

```
trait MyTrait[T] {
  def f(x: T): Int
}

class Foo extends MyTrait[Double] {
  def f(x: Double) = 1
}

class Bar extends MyTrait[String] {
  def f(x: String) = 2
}

val fooInstance: Foo = new Foo
val barInstance: Bar = new Bar
val myTraitList: List[MyTrait[_]] = List(fooInstance, barInstance)

println(fooInstance.getClass)
// prints "class MyExample$Foo"
println(barInstance.getClass)
// prints "class MyExample$Bar"

println(myTraitList(0).getClass)
// prints "class MyExample$Foo", so the list is preserving object classes and not just "MyTrait[_]"
println(myTraitList(1).getClass)
// prints "class MyExample$Bar", again, preserving object class

println(fooInstance.f(1.0))
// prints "1"
println(barInstance.f("blah"))
// prints "2"

println(myTraitList(0).f(1.0))
// this is where things break:
// "type mismatch; found : Double(1.0) required: _$3 where type _$3"
// so, the list element knows it's an instance of Foo (as indicated by getClass), but has lost the overloaded definition of f

println(myTraitList(1).f("blah"))
// the same error occurs on the Bar instance:
// "type mismatch; found : String("blah") required: _$3 where type _$3"
```

If I hard-code a `myTraitList(0).asInstanceOf[Foo].f(1.0)`, it (predictably) works just fine.  So, I tried to create a function to do that at run time:

```
def castToCorrectChildClass(o: MyTrait[_], label: Char): MyTrait[_] = {
  return label match {
    case 'f' => o.asInstanceOf[Foo]
    case 'b' => o.asInstanceOf[Bar]
    case _ => o
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, this is subject to the same problems:

```
println(castToCorrectChildClass(myTraitList(0), 'f').f(1.0))
// type mismatch; found : Double(1.0) required: _$2 where type _$2
```

One solution is to make a `List[MyTrait[Any]]` to store the instances and make the type parameter covariant: `trait MyTrait[+T]`.  Unfortunately, in my real-world code, I need it to be invariant for other reasons, so I can't use this workaround.  I've also tried using ClassTags and TypeTags to remember the child class thinking this were a reflection-related problem, but I didn't have any luck (and I suspect that that's not the intended use case for these, anyway, though perhaps I'm mistaken).

Any suggestions?  I'd love to have a flexible collection of unknown number (so, no `Tuples`) of child objects extending the same trait but with different types as per user input gathered at run time, and I'm happy to accept the trade-off of doing bookkeeping to ensure I don't mis-cast (or mis-`asInstanceOf`) an object back to the incorrect type, but I can't seem to get it working.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you want to do, but the problem you are facing is because the type of your `myTraitList` is similar to having a `List[MyTrait[Any]]`. Since the type is `_` the compiler doesn't know if it's `Bar` or `Foo`. Thankfully Scala provides Pattern Matching that allows you do condition on the type of an object.

#### Solution 1

```
def conditionalDo(x: MyTrait[_]) = {
    x match {
        case i: Foo => println("doing foo() stuff")
        case j: Bar => println("doing bar() stuff")
        case _ => println("error!")
    }
}

myTraitList.foreach(conditionalDo)
```

---

#### Solution 2

```
trait MyTrait {
  def f(x: Any): Int
}

class Foo extends MyTrait {
  def f(x: Any) = {
    x match {
       case i: Int => 1
       case _ => -1
    }
  }
}

class Bar extends MyTrait {
  def f(x: Any) = {
    x match {
       case j: String => 2
       case _ => -1
    }
  }
}

val fooInstance: Foo = new Foo
val barInstance: Bar = new Bar

val myTraitList: List[MyTrait] = List(fooInstance, barInstance)
myTraitList(0).f(1) // returns 1
myTraitList(1).f("s") // returns 2
```

Comment: Thanks marios, but the problem then is that I need to hard-code the operation I'd like to execute the object within the pattern matching code.  I'd like to essentially retrieve an object from the list at run time and cast it to the appropriate class (so, a `Foo`, or a `Bar`), so that I may then execute other arbitrary code on it (like `Foo.f()` or other methods).  I don't want to have a pattern match specifically for executing `f()`, one for `f2()`, or whatever other methods exist in `MyTrait`, and I think that's what the `conditionalDo` solution is pointing toward.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Collections are abstracted around a single type (e.g., `List[Int]`). If you have a collection with different types, then the more generic denominator needs to be the type of your class. In your case, is a `List[MyTrait[_]]`. If you need a collection that remembers the type of each element, then Scala has Tubles to do that. `val myTraitCollection = (fooInstance, barInstance)`. You can then access it as myTraitCollection._1 and myTraitCollection._2 with all the type information preserved. I can add this to the answer if this is what you want to do.

Comment: Yes, exactly, I want to have a collection with different types but a shared `Trait`.  For instance, a `List` of `MyTrait`s of any type.  The problem comes in when I attempt to retrieve an element of this `List` and cast it back to its original (child) class, like `Foo` or `Bar`.  `Tuple`s won't work for me because their arity must be known at compile time.  `HList`s from `shapeless` are more flexible, but you still can't have them with arbitrary arity determined at run time, hence my dependence on some kind of collection...  Again, thanks for your help!

Comment: I am sure there is a better way to do what you need. If you know that element at position 1 is Foo and at 2 is Bar then why not use a Tuble? If you want to have an arbitrary long list of stuff how would you know that element on position (say) 234 is of type Foo()? You either use pattern matching or you have a base method with the same input types that is implemented differently by each super class.

Comment: Thanks for your continued help, marios.  Tuples would be a great solution if I knew arity at compile time.  I want to parse user input and create a list of objects on the fly (of length known only at run time) according to that input. Your second solution is closer, but omits the type generics (which I suspect may be related to the difficulty of this problem). I can't help but feel that what I'm trying to do is basic object-orientism: I have children of a parent class that I'd like to store together in a list and identify their class via reflection.  Indeed, `getClass` works fine, but not `f`.

Comment: About my use case: I have probability distributions of different type that operate over different support.  So, `MyTrait[T]` is a `ProbabilityDistribution[T]`, and `Foo` could be `GaussianDistribution extends ProbabilityDistribution[Double]` while `Bar` could be `GeometricDistribution extends ProbabilityDistribution[Int]`.  They each implement a `density(x: T)` function to evaluate the probability at a point on their appropriate support.  I want to allow users to create arbitrary joint distributions at run-time.  Hence lists of `ProbabilityDistribution[_]`.  Does this help clarify?